# height of iframe collapsing when vertical align center

Tags: html, css, iframe, flexbox

I have the following code that displays the `iframe` on top left part of the screen. I want to keep the same dimensions of the frame and align it so that the center of `iframe` and the text on right hand side of screen are on same horizontal level. 
If I use the  `align-items:center;` the frame collapses. How to fix it?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .container{
                display:flex;
                flex-direction:row;
                /*align-items: center;*/

            }
            .column{
                flex:1 1 0px;
                /*align-self: center;*/
            }

            iframe{
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
                max-height: 50vh;
                border-style:solid;
                border-color: black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container" id="interests_container">
            <div class="column">
                <iframe> </iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <h1 id="interests">Interests</h1>
                <p> abcd abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd</p>
                <p> abcd abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd</p>
                <p> abcd abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd</p>
                <p> abcd abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd</p>
                <p> abcd abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd</p>
                <p> abcd abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd</p>
                <p> abcd abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd</p>
                <p> abcd abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd</p>
                <p> abcd abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd</p>
                <p> abcd abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container" id="photos_container">
            <div class="column">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note: I have already seen [Expanding iframe within Flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33270525/expanding-iframe-within-flexbox) but this did not help me.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:**

This is rather a workaround than a solution to your problem. But maybe it helps in your situation.

**Workaround**

Instead of flex-centering `.column` you could keep the column stretched the full height (by not applying `align-self: center` or by applying `align-self: stretched`) and center the iframe inside the column instead.

One solution to center the iframe would be to apply this CSS to the iframe:

```
position:relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Here is a JSFiddle with the workaround I just described:
https://jsfiddle.net/arb102tc/1/